# Mysql JSON update multiple object values in an array

Tags: mysql, json

I have the following data in a `meta` json column and need to rename the `Visual Arts` interests.

```json
{
  "industries": [
    {
      "name": "Science",
      "id": 1,
      "interests": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Visual Arts"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Data Science"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Arts",
      "id": 2,
      "interests": [
        {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "Music"
        },
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Visual Arts"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have managed to rename the industry name with this statement:

```sql
UPDATE table
SET meta = JSON_REPLACE(meta, JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_SEARCH(meta, 'all', 'old_name')), 'new_name')
```

This works because the JSON_SEARCH returns one path: `$.industries[0].name`

How can I update the **interests** if there are multiple values to be updated?

Running the above update statement to update the `Visual Arts` interest results in an error:

```
Query 1 ERROR: Invalid JSON path expression. The error is around character position 1.
```

I assume it's because there are two paths returned from the statement:

```sql
SELECT JSON_SEARCH(meta, 'all', 'Visual Arts')
FROM table
```

Results in:

```
["$.industries[0].interests[0].name", "$.industries[1].interests[1].name"]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**
This query works:

```sql
SELECT JSON_REPLACE(meta, '$.industries[0].interests[0].name', 'new_name', '$.industries[1].interests[1].name', 'new_name')
FROM job_requirements
```

Is there a way to convert

```sql
["$.industries[0].interests[0].name", "$.industries[1].interests[1].name"]
```

into

```sql
'$.industries[0].interests[0].name', 'new_name', '$.industries[1].interests[1].name', 'new_name'
```

Comment: If it is common to make changes like that, you should not use JSON, but instead use multiple tables a la RDBMS.

Comment: I couldn't agree more. Unfortunately, changing it is not an option.

Comment: Changing jobs is an option?  It sounds like you were hired to take care of the database, but are not allowed to do so.  (I do understand that the conversion would be non-trivial.)

Comment: Welcome to the [Inner-Platform Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner-platform_effect) antipattern. You now get to implement a whole DBMS within a DBMS.

Comment: What does `SELECT VERSION();` return? I'd like to know if you can use `JSON_TABLE()`, which requires MySQL 8.0.

Comment: Okay, I have done some tests using `JSON_TABLE()` assuming you can use MySQL 8.0. But I still find no good solution to do this update in a single query. The best I can come up with is that you can change only one value at a time. This really is totally the wrong design for what you need to do. If it were me, I'd insist on changing the code design to avoid using JSON.

Comment: Thanks Bill. I’m using MySql 8.0. I’d appreciate it if you can share  the JSON_TABLE suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my experimental attempt, though it fails. I'm posting this because you asked to see what I had tried. I don't claim this is a full solution to your question.

```
drop table if exists mytable;

create table mytable (
  id serial primary key,
  meta json
);

insert into mytable set meta = '...your example data...';

SELECT mytable.id, j.*
FROM mytable CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(
  mytable.meta,
  '$.industries[*]' COLUMNS(
    industry_num FOR ORDINALITY,
    industry_name VARCHAR(20) PATH '$.name',
    NESTED PATH '$.interests[*]' COLUMNS(
      interest_num FOR ORDINALITY,
      interest_name VARCHAR(20) PATH '$.name'
    )
  )
) AS j;
```

Output:

```
+----+--------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+
| id | industry_num | industry_name | interest_num | interest_name |
+----+--------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+
|  1 |            1 | Science       |            1 | Visual Arts   |
|  1 |            1 | Science       |            2 | Data Science  |
|  1 |            2 | Arts          |            1 | Music         |
|  1 |            2 | Arts          |            2 | Visual Arts   |
+----+--------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+
```

Now that we have a method for identifying the array index at each level of the JSON nested objects, we can try to UPDATE the value:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT mytable.id, j.*
  FROM mytable CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(
    mytable.meta,
    '$.industries[*]' COLUMNS(
      industry_num FOR ORDINALITY,
      industry_name VARCHAR(20) PATH '$.name',
      NESTED PATH '$.interests[*]' COLUMNS(
        interest_num FOR ORDINALITY,
        interest_name VARCHAR(20) PATH '$.name'
      )
    )
  ) AS j
)
UPDATE mytable JOIN cte USING (id)
SET meta = JSON_REPLACE(meta, CONCAT('$.industries[', cte.industry_num-1, '].interests[', cte.interest_num-1, '].name'), 'New Interest Name')
WHERE cte.interest_name = 'Visual Arts';
```

The problem that I have not solved is that this appears to only do one replacement.

JSON_REPLACE() takes variable arguments, so you can change the value at more than one path, but constructing that call would require dynamic SQL. I'm not interested in doing any more work on this, because in my opinion, the work above should demonstrate that managing this data in JSON is already more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: Thank you for sharing, Bill